# dropldown links not working after firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am following an angular tutorial on Udemy. I am able to open the bootstrap navbar dropdown links in local host, but not after hosting to firebase(Other navbar links work as expected). Pls help

I land at he following 404 error:

**404
Page Not Found
The specified file was not found on this website. Please check the URL for mistakes and try again.
Why am I seeing this?
This page was generated by the Firebase Command-Line Interface. To modify it, edit the 404.html file in your project's configured public directory.**

***index.html:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Oshop</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ffb6f1d88864b80c037e.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.10b7c76792e4769182f0.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

***firebase.json:***

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by modifying my firebase.json file to the following:

```
"rewrites": [{
      "source": "/public/**",
      "destination": "/public.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }]
```